# Scoring Wizard Cox regression survival model

Tags: wizard, spss, scoring, survival-analysis

I have estimated a Cox regression model. This model will predict the duration of a certain car ownership and is depending on income household size and age.

I would like to run the model on a different database, to see the effect of changing social factors on car ownership. I therefore saved the model outcome in a xml document.

Then i use this document as the input for the Scoring wizard and click next. 
The next step isn't completely clear to me, it shows that all the variables, depending and independent, are predictors. But shouldn't the duration variable be a target variable? Now the model will take the censored variable as a target value. (the censored variable shows whether the changes has taken place).

I would like to estimate the new duration. However i think that the predicted value of this models is the probability of surviving.

My question is thus how can i make the duration variable the target value and how should i otherwise interpret the predicted value?

Kind regards, 
Marlon

Comment: The model doesn't predict the duration - it gives the probability of "dying" given a set of covariates and a particular duration. What do you want the duration estimate to be? When the cumulative probability of dying is 50%, 90%? You could estimate these values over a grid of durations, or just figure out this exact value yourself given the model.

Comment: Hi Andy Thank you so much for replaying! I know that you will calculated the probability of leaving the state you are in( so if you are alive you will calculate the change of dying).Im not estimating models about dying, but about buying another car. I would like to use the estimated coefficients and variables for policy evaluation(so to see how car ownership will change due to this change according to the estimated model) I need the duration to see what the influence is of changing the price and keeping the same model and being able to compare them.